# angularjs scope two values keeping pointing to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

Hi I'm trying to copy a scope value from one to another scope.  For example:

```
  var items=$scope.order.invoicewindow.items;
  $scope.order.orderwindow.items=items;
```

However right both scopes are pointing to each other.  So if I change       $scope.order.orderwindow = "abc", $scope.order.invoicewindow.items also becomes "abc" (which I don't want.  I only want $scope.order.orderwindow = "abc").

Thanks

Comment: They are passing pointers to a memory location. Change the second line to $scope.order.orderWindow.items = angular.copy(items);

Comment: This case is impossible, "abc" is a primitive value (string) and never get assigned by reference. javascript only assign objects by reference so you should use `angular.copy` if you need a copy of an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**angular.copy(source, [destination]);**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

```
var items= "YourValue";
angular.copy(items, $scope.order.invoicewindow.items);
$scope.order.invoicewindow.items = angular.copy(items); //Or You can also use this style
```